# np select if statement to return a value for a conditional statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, if-statement

I want to create a new column that returns a value of 1 if the below condition is true and 2 if false and am not sure why the below isn't working?

```
t1 = x['timestamp_1'] < x['timestamp_2']


x['new'] = np.select([t1], [1], default=2)
```

Comment: `np.where(cond,valueiftrue,valueiffalse)`

Comment: Is `pd.x['']` a typo? should it be `x['column']`?

Answer (score 1):

use [numpy where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
#convert both columns to pd.to_datetime

x[['timestamp_1','timestamp_2']] = x[['timestamp_1','timestamp_2']].apply(pd.to_datetime,errors='coerce')

t1 = x['timestamp_1'] < x['timestamp_2']
x['new'] = np.where(t1,1,2)
```

which functions like:

```
np.where(cond,valueiftrue,valueiffalse)
```

Comment: when I try to create a new column as

x['new'] = np.where(t1,1,2) I get error as below

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: wait sorry  - it worked but it is giving a value of 2 for all rows, even when it should be 1?

do I need to convert to datetime prior? @anky_91

Comment: @Chris90 : check edited answer. :) Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
#Convert to datetime
x['timestamp_1'] = pd.to_datetime(x['timestamp_1'])
x['timestamp_2'] = pd.to_datetime(x['timestamp_2'])
t1 = x['timestamp_1'] < x['timestamp_2']

x['new']  = np.where(t1, 1, 2)
```

If the condition is true it will return 1 else it will return 2.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this it gives a value of 2 for all rows even when should be 1?

t1 = x['time_1'] < x['time_2']


x['new'] = np.where(t1, 1, 2)

Comment: Are your columns time1 and time2 converted to datetime type? If they are strings, it will work as you said. Convert them using `x['time1'] = pd.to_datetime(x['time1']` and similary for the other column

Answer (score 0):

You can use the intuitive list comprehension **after** you convert your timestamps  (pd.to_datetime), like this:

```
df['new'] = [1 if x==True else 2 for x in list(df.timestamp_1 < df.timestamp_2)]
```